# finding words surround by quotations perl

Tags: regex, perl

I am reading another perl file line by line and need to find any words or set of words surround by single or double quotations. This is an example of the code I am reading in:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my $string = 'Hello World!';
print "$string\n";
```

Basically, I need to find and print out 'Hello World!' and "$string\n".

I've read my file in fine and stored its contents in an array. From there I'm looping over each line and find the desired set of words in the quotations using regex as such:

```
for(@contents) {
   if(/\"|\'[^\"|\']*\"|\'/) {
       print $_."\n";
   }
}
```

which gives me the following output:

```
my $string = 'Hello World!';
print "$string\n";
```

I tried splitting the contents by whitespace and then trying to find a match, but that gives me this:

```
'Hello
World!'
"$string\n";
```

I've tried numerous solutions other suggested on here but to no avail. I have also tried Text::ParseText and using parse_line, but that gives me the complete wrong output.

Any ideas that could help me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just need to add some capturing parenthesis to your regex, instead of printing the whole line

```
use strict;
use warnings;

while (<DATA>) {
    if(/(["'][^"']*["'])/) {
        print "$1\n";
    }
}

__DATA__
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my $string = 'Hello World!';
print "$string\n";
```

Note, there are plenty of flaws in your regex though.  For example `'\''` Won't match properly.  Neither will `"He said 'boo'"`.  To get closer you'll have to do some balanced parenthesis checking, but there isn't going to be any perfect solution.

For a solution that is a little closer, you could use the following:

```
if(/('(?:(?>[^'\\]+)|\\.)*'|"(?:(?>[^"\\]+)|\\.)*")/) {
```

That would take care of my above exceptions and also strings like `print "how about ' this \" and ' more \n";`, but there are still edge cases like the use of [`qq{}`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/qq.html) or [`q{}`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/q.html).  Not to mention strings that span more than one line.

In other words, if your goal is perfect, this project may be outside of the scope of most people's skills, but hopefully the above will be of some help.

Comment: Thanks for your help mate, I struggle with regex and definitely need to look into it more! Your first solution works for what I need so far but I will need something more extensive down the track, I just want to get it working so I can move onto other parts of the script. Eventually I will have to handle multiple lines and more complex strings (with quotes in quotes etc) so your more solid solution will be a start.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you can have more than one "string" to capture per line, one solution could be:

```
while(my $line=<STDIN>) {
    while( $line =~ /[\'\"](.*?)[\'\"]/g ) {
        print "matched: '$1'\n";
    }
}
```

ie, input:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my $string = 'Hello World!' . 'asdsad';
print "$string\n";
```

and executing the code will give you:

```
matched: 'Hello World!'
matched: 'asdsad'
matched: '$string\n'
```

Comment: The regex would also match `''` and `" "`.  Are these 'words?'

Comment: @Kenosis It would depend on what you want to capture. When i read the original question I thought the author was trying to catch all "strings" that where printed out on the code.

Comment: On second look, I think you're correct.  The OP's regex also matches 0+ chars between quotes.  I believe I was distracted by the OP's *"...find any words or set of words..."* spec, and didn't think an empty string or one containing only whitespace would be considered containing a 'word'.  On the other hand, perhaps the OP just didn't realize the consequences of `[^"']*`.

Comment: @Kenosis - you're right in a sense. It shouldn't be a word and I will account for empty strings such as '' and "" down the track, but I was stuck and just wanted to get a simple match to work. So I was aware, but I'm still learning so baby steps! Thanks for reminding me to update it!

Comment: @mgo1977 - thanks mate, your answer works except that it doesn't print the surrounding quotations, but adding parenthesis will do it. Now to match more complex situations!