# Find single and double quoted strings and define which one was found in Perl

Tags: regex, perl

I've got the text file like that (it has many lines)

```
This is "double quote" and 'single quote' and another 'single'
This line has "double"
```

I need to split lines into strings (everything that within single or double quotes)
The output should be the following:

```
"double quote" 
'single quote' 
'single' 
"double"
```

I use the following regex which works perfectly

```
my @line_array = $string =~ /["']+(.*?)["']+/g;
```

but the output is:

```
double quote
single quote
single 
double
```

I just can't determine what kind of quote was found and how to print them in a sequence other. Drives me crazy

Many thanks

Comment: It's a case of misplaced parenthesis.  You haven't _captured_ the quotes.

Comment: any idea how it can be fixed?

Comment: Can your quoted strings contain newlines? If so, you need to do things differently.

Comment: @Max_S do you know about capturing groups in Perl regex? if so, you can solve this puzzle very quickly!

Comment: Possible duplicate of this post from yesterday: [finding words surround by quotations perl](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22418745/finding-words-surround-by-quotations-perl)

Comment: to devnull - thanks mate very much. It helped a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply change the parenthesis to capture the quotes as well. So:

```
my @line_array = $string =~ /(["']+.*?["']+)/g;
```