# Need to pick up everything in double or single quotes from the file in Perl

Tags: regex, perl

I'm new to Perl. there is file that has multiple lines. All lines have words inside single or double quotes. Sometimes these words come to another line. For example:

```
  there is word "apple" inside quotes. Another 'single' quotes 
  second line with 'different' string. Here the double "line 
                                         string"
```

I use

```
   while ($value = <$file>) {
   my @array = $str =~ /(['"]+.*?['"]+)/g; 

  }
```

to pick up words but I don't know how to get two or more lines string in quotes. I there any regex solution not using Perl modules or internal commands?

the desired ouput:

```
"apple" 
'single' 
'Different'
"line string"
```

Thanks

Comment: What are you trying to do, remove the `"`, `'` and new lines when inside quotes?

Comment: i've just edited my question

Comment: OK so to put it simple you want to fix lines that have been passed to the next line like in your example `"Line\nstring"` \n here representing the newline.

Comment: yes, but I even have no idea how to pick them up

Comment: possible duplicate of [finding words surround by quotations perl](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22418745/finding-words-surround-by-quotations-perl)

Comment: Why isn't 'different' part of your desired output?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use warnings;
use strict;

use Data::Dumper;

local $/;

my $data = <DATA>;

my @strings = map { s/\s*\n\s*/ /; $_ } ( $data =~ m/((?:'[^']+')|(?:"[^"]+"))/sg );

print Dumper(\@strings);


__DATA__
there is word "apple" inside quotes. Another 'single' quotes 
second line with 'different' string. Here the double "line 
string"
```