# Matching multiline string in file using perl regex

Tags: regex, string, perl, multiline

I am reading in another perl file and trying to find all strings surrounded by quotations within the file, single or multiline. I've matched all the single lines fine but I can't match the mulitlines without printing the entire line out, when I just want the string itself. For example, heres a snippet of what I'm reading in:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use warnings;
use strict;

# assign variable

my $string = 'Hello World!';
my $string4 = "chmod";
my $string3 = "This is a fun 
    multiple line string, please match";
```

so the output I'd like is

```
'Hello World!';
"chmod";
"This is a fun multiple line string, please match";
```

but I am getting:

```
'Hello World!';
my $string4 = "chmod";
my $string3 = "This is a fun 
    multiple line string, please match";
```

This is the code I am using to find the strings - all file content is stored in @contents:

```
my @strings_found = ();
my $line; 
for(@contents) {
    $line .= $_;
}

if($line =~ /(['"](.?)*["'])/s) {
    push @strings_found,$1;
}

print @strings_found;
```

I am guessing I am only getting 'Hello World!'; correctly because I am using the $1 but I am not sure how else to find the others without looping line by line, which I would think would make it hard to find the multi line string as it doesn't know what the next line is.

I know my regex is reasonably basic and doesn't account for some caveats but I just wanted to get the basic catch most regex working before moving on to more complex situations.

Any pointers as to where I am going wrong?

Comment: I've also tried to replace the '\n' with spaces but that hasn't worked.

Answer (score 5):

Couple big things, you need to search in a `while` loop with the `g` modifier on your regex.  And you also need to turn off greedy matching for what's inside the quotes by using `.*?`.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $contents = do {local $/; <DATA>};

my @strings_found = ();

while ($contents =~ /(['"](.*?)["'])/sg) {
    push @strings_found, $1;
}

print "$_\n" for @strings_found;

__DATA__
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use warnings;
use strict;

# assign variable

my $string = 'Hello World!';
my $string4 = "chmod";
my $string3 = "This is a fun 
    multiple line string, please match";
```

Outputs

```
'Hello World!'
"chmod"
"This is a fun
    multiple line string, please match"
```

You aren't the first person to search for help with this homework problem.  Here's a more detailed answer I gave to ... well ... you ;) [`finding words surround by quotations perl`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22418745/finding-words-surround-by-quotations-perl/22418809#22418809)

Comment: Thanks for your help mate! Solutions works well but has highlighted issues in my regex... but for another time!

Comment: Yeah, as I said in your previous question, this is a much harder problem than it would appear on the surface.  Good luck in your continued explorations

Comment: Thanks for your help on both, its helping me get my head around a few things!

Answer (score 1):

regexp matching (in perl and generally) are greedy by default. So your regexp will match from 1st ' or " to last. Print the length of your @strings_found array. I think it will always be just 1 with the code you have.

Change it to be not greedy by following * with a ?
/('"*?["'])/s
I think.

It will work in a basic way. Regexps are kindof the wrong way to do this if you want a robust solution. You would want to write parsing code instead for that. If you have different quotes inside a string then greedy will give you the 1 biggest string. Non greedy will give you the smallest strings not caring if start or end quote are different.

Read about greedy and non greedy.
Also note the /m multiline modifier.
http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Regular-Expressions

Comment: Thanks for the input. Have you got an example of the parsing code your talking about? Doesn't have to be an exact solution for my question, just one that I could use to develop my own answer.

Comment: No example handy. I'd be thinking of doing something complicated with strtok in c :-/. Using regexps make sure you try non greedy. That will get simple basic solution working. Seperate out quotes in regexp too might give you better result if you need to handle quotes inside strings? . . . Maybe /(("[^"]*?")|('[^']*?'))*?/s sorry no time I'm not going to play with that now.

Comment: No worries, just thought I'd ask, google is my friend!